# I try to install subkey but get empty installation error

Tags: substrate

I want to install subkey to process my old Edgeware account but I get this issue:

````
Warning: Aleth (formerly cpp-ethereum) has been removed from Homebrew. Please install binary releases from https://github.com/ethereum/aleth/releases.
==> Cloning https://github.com/ethereum/aleth.git
Updating /Users/eduardoagut/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cpp-ethereum--git
==> Checking out branch master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
HEAD is now at a3b9320 Merge pull request #5885 from ethereum/testupdate
Entering 'cmake/cable'
Entering 'evmc'
Entering 'scripts/dopple'
Entering 'test/jsontests'
/Users/eduardoagut/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cpp-ethereum--git/cmake/cable
/Users/eduardoagut/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cpp-ethereum--git/evmc
/Users/eduardoagut/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cpp-ethereum--git/scripts/dopple
/Users/eduardoagut/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cpp-ethereum--git/test/jsontests
Error: Empty installation```
````

Comment: The logs you are showing are related to installing Ethereum. To install subkey you should follow the instructions here: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/overview/getting-started#install-subkey-locally

Comment: The command that you suggest gives error:cargo install --force --path ./bin/utils/subkey subkey
multirust: no default toolchain configured

Comment: You need to install a rust toolchain with `multirust`. This is not a Substrate/Subkey issue.

Comment: how can I do that?